# How to create new empty C++ file without writing it on disk?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Quite often I want to create new file in IDE just to format/edit it. After I'm done I just copy the contents and close without saving.

One example usage is when I'm editing badly formatted code from someone's question, or my own.

In Qt creator, this does not seem to be simple task. When I click on [image: New file or project] what I see is a list of templates:

[image: image description]

Any of these will ask you for file name when you want to use it. This creates a file (undesirable) not mentioning the whole process is pretty slow.

Is there some other way to create empty file that is not saved in filesystem? Or most importantly **faster way to create empty file** for temporary text editing - that is one that doesn't go through two dialogs? It must be C++ file because I need C++ highlighting and code snippets.

Comment: Why not reused a dedicated empty project done for that ? So you already have one main.cpp on disk, that you can format, and no need to save it.

Comment: Since its a temporary file, why can't you just save it in your systems temporary file folder? You could also use a different editor.

Comment: In MSVS I have a "test" project that I dump random stuff into.  This way I do not mess with anything I am actually doing in MSVS.

Comment: @JasonC well, the question is how to do this in QtCreator, not just how to do this...

Comment: Others have said the same thing I do which is a dedicated file just for this. However is it really life or death if your temporary document gets written to the HDD?

Comment: @Galik No, the primary problem is time spent opening the temporary document vs time spent making new file in other editors and IDEs. And one reason I prefer QtCreator is code snippets, which work really well there.

Comment: Right. So like i said in qt creator create a new file in your systems temporary file folder. That's what that folder is for.

Comment: @JasonC I already explained in OP that such solution is quite slow, which is annoying when I just want to change indentation or something similar. Is my post hard to understand? Non of the comments addresses this problem so either my post is poorly written or all commenters here didn't read the post completely.

Comment: Using the temp folder is quick (just type /var/tmp or c:\windows\temp in the directory box in the new file dialog...) but if you just want to change indentation quickly then use an online code indenter... Your question isnt unclear its just silly: You're asking how to hammer in a nail with a screwdriver and then insisting that there must be a way when you're told to just use a hammer. You're also ignoring easy qt creator suggestions but really just use the right tool for the job and be done with it... You can't not save a file in qt creator, that's not what that tool is for. Bummer.

Comment: @JasonC When asking the question, I didn't know the feature isn't implemented. I couldn't find it, I couldn't google it - so I posted a question. Not sure what's silly about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a scratch buffer via File>New File or Project. There is a wizard in there that.

Comment: This is a valid answer, but a bit terse.  It is found in: File>New File or Project>General>ScratchBuffer

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using notepad++ honestly. It is super simple and gets the job done.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - how to do it in QtCreator.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but your question did not specify that you only wanted solutions within QT:
"is there some other way to create empty file that is not saved in filesystem? Or most importantly faster way to create empty file for temporary text editing - that is one that doesn't go through two dialogs? It must be C++ file because I need C++ highlighting and code snippets."
A faster way without saving to filesystem to facilitate temporary text editing would be to use a more basic text editor as I stated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a temp project for that purpose and then just open it when you need a temp project.

Comment: Correlation != causation. I did not downvote your post. Anyway, qtcreator was one of the question tags. Would you answer question tagged Visual Studio with answer that uses Gedit?